# Angular 13 application will not start when run from local file system

Tags: angular

I am working with a touch screen controller (Crestron TS-1070) that runs an Angular project from its local file system.

In the past this worked up to Angular 12.x by setting the Base Href to `./`

As of Angular 13, the project no longer starts when run on the hardware or run from a local folder (without ng serve) on a computer. (with Angular 12 Projects would run both on the Crestron Hardware and from my PCs local file system)

Currently if I try and run the Angular app locally on my PC, it fails to load due to a CORS error (which is strange, because even with it running off the local FS, all content is still coming from the same location)

`Access to script at 'file:///C:/...../ng13test/dist/project/runtime.0f2b2e483b3be070.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy`

I have tried running chrome with the `--disable-web-security` flag just to see if it is really a CORS issue and I am presented with a different issue:

`Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

Unfortunately there is no console that I can access on the Crestron hardware to see if the same issue is occurring there, but I would assume that it is the same issue.

I have tried setting APP_BASE_HREF to the actual file path of where to project is stored on the Crestron hardware to no success.

The Crestron hardware is running Chromium 87.

Comment: Could you install apache or nginx on Crestron hardware ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, We do not have Firmware level access to the Crestron Panel to change its behavior or install other packages, All we can do is provide a SPA that is executed by the built in browser at boot.

Comment: There is no origin when running off of the file system, so there have always been CORS issues (Cross **Origin** Resource Sharing) with it, as long as CORS has been around. I'm not even sure if they support running from the file system, considering everything in the framework (CLI, etc.) is geared around running from an HTTP server. In any case, you may want to check Angular's [browser support policy](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support), which says it supports the latest version of Chrome only. Considering the current version is 97, 87 is quite old, but I don't know what Chromium is at.

Answer (score 0):

within your HTML delete the following:

```
<base href="/" />
```

then add this to your module file providers:

```
{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: './' }
```

this works on angular 13-16 as far as I have tested on x60 and x70 model touch panels running latest firmware.